# What is uid in snort means

Tags: networking, snort, attacks, ids

I was writing a snort rule for the specific exploit and then came across one solution that details as "uid=0(root)". Can someone explain what is that and why it is mentioned in order to capture the packet containing root content in it.

Answer (score 0):

The first search result on a Google search for `snort uid=0` finds a useful  product documentation page with an excellent explanation https://www.snort.org/rule_docs/1-498

> The string `"uid=0(root)"` is an output of an `"id"` command indicating that the user has "root" privileges. Seeing such a response indicates that some user, connected over the network to a target server, has root privileges.
> ...
> This may be post-attack behavior and can be indicative of the successful exploitation of a vulnerable system.

In other words: Most remote exploits, that will grant an attacker access to a vulnerable system, won’t immediately grant full (root) access to a system. Once granted unprivileged access an attacker will still need to try to find a second vulnerability which they can abuse to escalate their limited access to full root privileges.

That string can be seen after they succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it clear.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers